# Outlier detection for blackbox function

Tags: outliers

I have a noisy and costly black-box function f(p1,p2,p3,p4), where I don't have any priors for noise. I have evaluated the function uniformly in pre-defined but different intervals for p1,p2,p3,p4. Assuming that function is smooth, I want to identify outliers so that I can reevaluate those points, and get a better estimation. Since the evaluation function is costly, I cannot afford to evaluate all points more than once.

I have been looking for functional data analysis (multivariate functional PCA etc.), but I was confused if multivariate functional data analysis is what I need. And I was also not sure if machine learning methods are suitable, s.t I am using f(p1,p2,p3,p4) as another variable in the dataset.

Thanks in advance